# Working with binary data in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, networking, binary, endianness

I'm writing a client for a binary socket protocol in PHP, and it's a pain. I'm currently using [`pack`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) to convert numbers into binary strings, but it's lacking. Two options `pack` has are:

- Write a signed 32 bit integer in machine byte order
- Write an insigned 32 bit integer in big endian byte order

But I need to write signed 32 bit integers in big endian order, as with Java's `DataOutputStream.writeInteger`. `pack` doesn't have that option.

Is there a way to do this with `pack`, or to transform the output of `pack`, or maybe a better library for working with binary data in PHP?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but here goes: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2454-PHP-Serialize-and-unserialize-binary-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification for PHP's `pack()` says that the unsigned/signed distinction only matters for `unpack()`, not `pack()`.

So just use the 32 bit network byte order option (`N`).

Comment: + 4 billion, doesn't that result in the same number? I also suspect this isn't very portable, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300840/force-php-integer-overflow

Comment: @Bart vna Heukelom: On further reflection, and checking the documentation, you can just use the unsigned option.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use the Zend Framework? If so, you can use the function `Zend_Io_Writer::writeInt32BE()`

> Writes signed 32-bit integer as
>   big-endian ordered binary data to the
>   stream.

Or else you should take a look at the [ZF-source](http://code.google.com/p/php-reader/source/browse/trunk/src/Zend/Io/Writer.php) how these guys handle this.