# Can I define PHP_INT_SIZE to 4 bytes on 64-bit system running PHP?

Tags: php, int

I am using PHP 5.3.

On my 32-bit system the size of an INT:

```
print "PHP_INT_MAX: " . PHP_INT_MAX . "\n";
print "PHP_INT_SIZE: " . PHP_INT_SIZE . " bytes (" . (PHP_INT_SIZE * 8) . " bits)\n";
```

- PHP_INT_MAX: **2147483647**
- PHP_INT_SIZE: **4 bytes (32 bits)**

However, part of an an encoding algorithm I am using relies on the fact that an int is the above size (4 bytes). When I run the code on my web host's server, it is a 64-bit system and the int size is twice as large.

Is there a way to force "(int)" cast to use the 32-bit size?

For example, assume the following code:

```
$test = 4170266799;
print $test;                     
print (int) $test;
```

On my **32-bit** system, the output is:

```
4170266799
-124700497
```

On my **64-bit** system, the output is:

```
4170266799
4170266799
```

Is it possible to force the value of an INT to be 4 bytes, even when the architecture changes from 32-bit to 64-bit?

Comment: I would fix the encoding algorithm...

Comment: Is this an instance of [the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/164291)?  What problem are you *really* trying to solve?

Comment: No, it is not an instance of the XY problem. I am converting portions of a large code base written in native compiled code. Part of that I am moving to PHP to be accessed from the web, however it must generate information in the same manner expected by my 32-bit application. That is why I rely on the INT size. I am choosing to do as close a conversion as possible instead of redesigning the logic to generate the same results. Fortunately, I now have it working.

Comment: @Mick, you can always use a pre-compiler that does the modification for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300840/force-php-integer-overflow/303856#303856) on Stack Overflow, I have found a solution that seems to work in my early tests:

```
function thirtyTwoBitIntval($value)
{                  
    if ($value < -2147483648)
    {
    return -(-($value) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
    elseif ($value > 2147483647)
    {
        return ($value & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
    return $value;
}


$test = 4170266799;
print $test;                     
print (int) $test;
print thirtyTwoBitIntval($test);
```

And the output on the **32-bit** system is:

```
4170266799  # $test = 4170266799
-124700497  # (int) $test
-124700497  # thirtyTwoBitIntval($test);
```

And the output on the **64-bit** system is:

```
4170266799  # $test = 4170266799
4170266799  # (int) $test
-124700497  # thirtyTwoBitIntval($test);
```

Comment: For me, your solution does not work, tests do fail. This solution does work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2123458/1140922

Answer (score 4):

No, this is very much dependant upon the platform itself:

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value
>   of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed).
>   64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does
>   not support unsigned integers.

And because the values that expose the integer size and integer maximum are constants, they can't be changed - being determined at compile-time of PHP based on the current system.

Not much consolation, but this is why relying on something such as a constant (that isn't yours to change, and is subject to change per build), or any kind of "sizeof` implementations are just as evil as magic numbers in code - don't do it. One thing that we can be sure of (at least, I hope!) is that 4 is and always will be 4, but not that *x*, *y*, or *z* will represent 4, even if they do now.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are correct that I cannot change the size of an INT in PHP. Fortunately, I have found a way to "cast" an INT to the size I expect on a 32-bit system, even when my code is running on a 64-bit system.

Comment: Do tell us how, Mick.