# PHP equivalent of Convert.ToInt32 in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, php, .net, vb.net, 32bit-64bit

I'm looking for a concise way to convert a 8-char string to an 32-bit signed integer.

See the reference for Convert.ToInt32 method on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx).

This is the current .NET code in VB:

```
Convert.ToInt32("c0f672d4", 16)
// returns -1057590572
```

How can I get the same return value using PHP 5.3+ for both 32-bit and 64-bit?

I imagine it may require a combination of [pack](http://php.net/pack)/[unpack](http://php.net/unpack) functions and [bitwise operators](http://php.net/operators.bitwise) but as yet have not found the right combination.

**Updated: 2013-07-10**
The following **only** works on 32-bit systems:

```
$str = 'c0f672d4';
$int = intval( substr( $str, 0, 4 ), 16 ); // read high 16 bit word
$int <<= 16; // shift hi word correct position
$int |= intval( substr( $str, 4, 4 ), 16 ); //  read low 16 bit word
echo $int;
// returns -1057590572
```

The problem with the above is that it **does not work** on 64-bit system. Instead I get the value `3237347344` using the above PHP code.

Any ideas for getting a consistent integer with PHP which is portable for 32-bit and 64-bit?

Comment: That snippet above, although doesn't produce the output you're after could be replaced with hexdec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently working for me on 32-bit and 64-bit systems, YMMV. Make sure you test, test, test!

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2123458/

```
function intval_32bits($value)
{
    $value = ($value & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    if ($value & 0x80000000) $value = -((~$value & 0xFFFFFFFF) + 1);
    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert from 64 bit two's complement +ve val to a 32 bit two's complement -ve value

```
function to_int32($value) {

    $intval = hexdec($value);

    // If 64 bit
    if (PHP_INT_SIZE === 8) {
        return ($intval - 0x100000000);
    }

    // 32 bit
    return $intval;
}
```

Comment: I've tested this on both 32-bit and 64-bit and it appears to be working. Thank you. Do you have more information where I can read more on this fix / solution?

Comment: Subsequently, I've come across some edge cases that didn't work out so I'm doing some more rigours testing with these two solutions:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2123458/156406
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8130131/156406