# Why two float variables with PHP_INT_MAX values are same unless one of them is added with value greater than 1025

Tags: php, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

```
<?php
$x=PHP_INT_MAX;
echo ((float)($x+1026)==(float)($x))?'EQUAL':'Not Equal';
```

I know floating point arithmetic is not exact and $x and $x+1 are so close together that they are rounded to the same floating point value and it shows the output as EQUAL if you use any number between 1 and 1025 but its  only after you use value beyond 1025 it will start giving output as 'Not Equal'. I want to know why? What's the reason behind it? Why only after 1025?

Comment: You need to start looking at the [bit-level representation of floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) and this will also vary depending on whether you're running 32-bit or 64-bit PHP

Comment: which PHP version do you have ? with my test I have "not equal" with "$x + 10" for exemple

Comment: Take a look at [this convertor](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), which allows you to see the float representation for different numbers

Comment: @mmm: my PHP version is 5.5.24 its Mac OS X 64 bit, I don't think float response is php version dependent, its something else.

Comment: @MarkBaker:Thanks for references, I will check it & get back to you.

Comment: Just because you're on a 64-bit operating system, doesn't automatically mean that you're running 64-bit PHP. You can check using the [PHP_INT_SIZE or PHP_INT_MAX constants](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) - on 32-bit PHP, PHP_INT_MAX is 2147483647; on 64-bit, it's 9223372036854775807; while PHP_INT_SIZE is 4 on 32-bit PHP, and 8 on 64-bit PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker:I have already checked it while working on it,my PHP_INT_MAX is 9223372036854775807 and PHP_INT_SIZE is 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With float, your assumption `$x == $x + 1` is not necessarily true:

```
$x=2;
echo ((float)($x+1)==(float)($x))?'EQUAL':'Not Equal';
```

yields "Not Equal".

In the converter linked in the comments (http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), you can reproduce this. decimal `2.0` yields `0x40000000`, decimal `3.0` yields `0x40400000`, so they're indeed different when it comes to IEEE754 float representation.

Whereas, e.g., decimal `0.1` cannot be represented as float: `0x3dcccccd`, which is `0.10000000149011612`.

What's decimal `9223372036854775807`? That's `0x5f000000`, which is `9.223372E18`, which is `9223372180000000000`.

What's decimal `9223372036854775808` (`PHP_MAX_INT + 1`)? That's `0x5f000000`, too.

What's decimal `9223372036854776832` (`PHP_MAX_INT + 1025`)? That's `0x5f000000`, too.

What's decimal `9223372036854776833` (`PHP_MAX_INT + 1026`)? That's `0x5f000000`, too.

They're all the same.

Whereas, e.g.: decimal `9223373000000000000` (`PHP_MAX_INT + 963145224193`)? That's `0x5f000001`, which is `9.223373E18`, which is `9223373000000000000`.

Now, why does:

```
((float)($x+1025)==(float)($x+1026))?'EQUAL':'Not Equal';
```

yield "Not Equal"?

You're adding an integer to `PHP_MAX_INT`.

```
$x=PHP_INT_MAX;
$y=PHP_INT_MAX-1;
$z=PHP_INT_MAX+1;
var_dump($x);
var_dump($y);
var_dump($z);
```

yields:

```
int(9223372036854775807)
int(9223372036854775806)
float(9.2233720368548E+18)
```

PHP implicitly converts integers too large to float. And that's where you're basically lost in PHP internals (at least in my opinion), because from here, you'll never know what will happen (without knowing PHP internals, feel free to correct me, though).

Notice this:

```
$x=PHP_INT_MAX;
$a=(float)($x+1025.0); // 1025 float
$b=(float)($x+1026.0); // 1026 float
$c=(float)($x+1025); // 1025 int
$d=(float)($x+1026); // 1026 int
var_dump($x);
var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
var_dump($c);
var_dump($d);
var_dump($a==$b);
var_dump($a===$b);
var_dump($c==$d);
var_dump($c===$d);
```

yields:

```
int(9223372036854775807)
float(9.2233720368548E+18)
float(9.2233720368548E+18)
float(9.2233720368548E+18)
float(9.2233720368548E+18)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

If you add an integer (`$x+1026`) to `PHP_MAX_INT`, it is converted to float, and when you add a float (`$x+1026.0`), it is float, too, of course. But, obviously, they're not the same internally, see the comparisons above.

Bottom line:

- Don't compare floats for equality
- Be careful about your casts; `(float)($x+1026)` is an integer addition, and afterwards casted to float, whereas `(float)($x+1026.0)` converts `$x` to float, then adds the float `1026.0`, then casts (superfluously) to float.

Edit: additionally, see:

- [Force PHP integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300840/force-php-integer-overflow)
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php